# Does it worth to put entity under @Transactional service layer if just for searching?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

In Spring MVC, I put most JPA `entity` (from domain layer) manipulation under `service` layer and for most `CRUD` actions, I have to make that service method or class `@Transactional`.

But, just thinking, if for a regular finder method, which is like

```
MyEntity myEntity = MyEntity.findByAliceAndBob(Alice alice, Bob bob);
```

So the questions are:

1. do we need to put it under a @Transactional method?
2. If not necessary and but still we do so, is there any performance cost?
3. If not necessary, so why not just call the finder method into controller?

Comment: Simple answers: 1. No. 2. Yes, you're opening a transaction and closing it when you don't need it (note that the impact on database depends on the vendor). 3. This can't be done since you could break the layered structure, the operations against your data source (in this case, a database) must be done by the DAO layer, not in the Service layer.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Thank you. To Q3 there is a little clarify: The question is actually can we just call(not define, just updated the post) that finder method from controller layer not in service layer. Agree finder method must defined in DAO layer.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza and if you could please put the comment as an answer I will close this post. I think your comment is clear enough to answer my question. :D

Answer (score 1):

Simple answers:

> do we need to put it under a @Transactional method?

No.

> If not necessary and but still we do so, is there any performance cost?

Yes, you're opening a transaction and closing it when you don't need it (note that the impact on database depends on the RDBMS vendor).

> If not necessary, so why not just call the finder method into controller?

You can do it, but IMO you shouldn't since you could break the layered structure. The operations against your data source (in this case, a database) must be done in the DAO layer, not in the Service layer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that contribute to that decision.

1) Are you using an open entityManager filter, or are you in auto-commit mode?

If you don't have an open persistence session, then every time you perform a persistence operation in auto-commit mode, you're building an entire new one out of scratch and then trashing it.  This can add up fast.  It can be useful in this case to group all of the reading a particular controller does into a single transaction, even if it is "inelegant" and mucks up the "pretty" abstraction SpringMVC offers.

2) Does your JPA dialect support readOnly transactions?

`@Transactional(readOnly = true)` can be a useful performance boost over running the query in auto-commit mode, especially if a large number of entities are being loaded.

3) Do you have distributed transactions?

Contacting the JTA server and starting a distributed transaction is probably not worth it for local atomic reads.

4) Are results potentially cached?

When you use Spring declarative transactions there is an issue where Spring will acquire a database connection and start a transaction before the persistence provider has any knowledge of what the intended operation is.  If the results are actually sitting in memory in the persistence provider and it has no need to talk to the database for this particular operation, that can be a bit of wasted effort. (Worrying about this is pretty aggressive micro-optimization IMO, the app server is probably pretty saturated if it starts to matter.)

Comment: Thank you. for Answer 1, is it better just not use `Transactional`? Answer 2, if we use `RealyOnly=true`, is it better than non-transactional mode for large scale of data? and for Answer 4, it seems using @Transactional is more likely an overkill for searching only.

Comment: 1) it depends on the entire operation.  If the framework is not automatically creating a persistence session, you may want to consider grouping your work together in a single @Transactional to avoid churning sessions. 2) if your provider and dialect support it, it will usually be better.  4) depends on the operation.  As soon as there's more than one actual query, using Transactional will almost always be better.  How sure of the future are you?

Comment: Also there is no such thing as "non-transactional mode", if you don't explicitly use a transaction you're just in auto-commit.